# Scala toString: parenthesize or not?

Tags: scala

I'd like this thread to be some kind of summary of pros/cons for overriding and calling `toString` with or without empty parentheses, because this thing still confuses me sometimes, even though I've been into Scala for quite a while.

So which one is preferable over another? Comments from Scala geeks, officials and OCD paranoids are highly appreciated.

Pros to `toString`:

- seems to be an obvious and natural choice at the first glance;
- most cases are trivial and just construct Strings on the fly without ever modifying internal state;
- another common case is to delegate method call to the wrapped abstraction:

  ```
  override def toString = underlying.toString
  ```

Pros to `toString()`:

- definitely not "accessor-like" name (that's how IntelliJ IDEA inspector complains every once in a while);
- might imply some CPU or I/O work (in cases where counting every `System.arrayCopy` call is crucial to performance);
- even might imply some mutable state changing (consider an example when first `toString` call is expensive, so it is cached internally to yield quicker calls in future).

So what's the best practice? Am I still missing something?

*Update*: this question is related specifically to `toString` which is defined on every JVM object, so I was hoping to find the *best practice*, if it ever exists.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281977/elements-of-scala-style.

Comment: Edited to explain, why it is not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's what *Programming In Scala* (section 10.3) has to say:

> The recommended convention is to use a parameterless method whenever
>   there are no parameters and the method accesses mutable state only by
>   reading fields of the containing object (in particular, it does not
>   change mutable state). This convention supports the uniform access
>   principle,1 which says that client code should not be affected by a
>   decision to implement an attribute as a field or method.

Here's what the (unofficial) *Scala Style Guide* (page 18) has to say:

> Scala allows the omission of parentheses on methods of arity-0 (no
>   arguments):

```
reply() 
// is the same as 
reply
```

> However, this syntax
>   should only be used when the method in question has no side-effects
>   (purely-functional). In other words, it would be acceptable to omit
>   parentheses when calling queue.size, but not when calling println().
>   This convention mirrors the method declaration convention given above.

The latter does not mention the Uniform Access Principle.

If your `toString` method can be implemented as a `val`, it implies the field is immutable. If, however, your class is mutable, `toString` might not always yield the same result (e.g. for `StringBuffer`). So *Programming In Scala* implies that we should use `toString()` in **two** different situations:

1) When its value is mutable

2) When there are side-effects

Personally I think it's more common and more consistent to ignore the first of these. In practice `toString` will almost never have side-effects. So (unless it does), always use `toString` and ignore the Uniform Access Principle (following the *Style Guide*): keep parentheses to denote side-effects, rather than mutability.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, I accepting this one. I actually agree that mutability and side effects have different semantics; the question is whether to interpret internal caching as side-effect or not (e.g. in concurrency-sensitive contexts). Anyway, I think this is an exact explanation I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: @incarnate Regarding caches, I don't think changing the length of time taken to retrieve a result is generally considered a side-effect (although you could credibly argue that it is), as functions make no promises about this.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you are missing something: Semantics.

If you have a method that simply gives back a value, you shouldn't use parens. The reason is that this blurs the line between `val`s and `def`s, satisfying the [Uniform Access Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle). E.g. consider the `size` method for collections. For fixed-sized vectors or arrays this can be just a `val`, other collections may need to calculate it.

The usage of empty parens should be limited to methods which perform some kind of side effect, e.g. `println()`, or a method that increases an internal counter, or a method that resets a connection etc.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I am pretty sure I know the difference between empty-paren and parameterless methods and the semantics behind Uniform Access. I was trying to find out whether it is possible to produce some strict rule like "Always use `toString`" or "Never use `toString()`". If you suggest to always stick to UAP and use `toString`, then please explain me the last case from my question (about caching results internally) -- how come internal caching is not a side effect?

Comment: If there is no way to distinguish if a value is cached or recalculated, you have no way to observe the side effect, so practically it didn't happen. Even in Haskell you can use mutable state, as long it is nicely wrapped and hence never observable. I think we should be even more forgiving in Scala by neglecting side effects which don't influence the program flow (e.g. logging).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend always using `toString`. Regarding your third "pro" to `toString()`:

> Might imply some mutable state changing (consider an example when first toString call is expensive, so it is cached internally to yield quicker calls in future).

First of all, `toString` generally *shouldn't* be an expensive operation. But suppose it is expensive, and suppose you do choose to cache the result internally. Even in that case, I'd say use `toString`, as long as the *result* of `toString` is always the same for a given state of the object (disregarding the state of the `toString` cache).

The only reason I would not recommend using `toString` without parens is if you have a code profiler/analyzer that makes assumptions based on the presence or absence of parens. In that case, follow the conventions set forth by said profiler. Also, if your `toString` is that complicated, consider renaming it to something else, like `expensiveToString`. It is unofficially expected that `toString` be a straightforward, simple function in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Not much argumentation in this answer but `GenTraversableOnce` alone declares the following defs without parentheses:

```
toArray
toBuffer
toIndexedSeq
toIterable
toIterator
toList
toMap
toSeq
toSet
toStream
toTraversable
```

Comment: Thanks for the list. I think there should be some sort of convention to prefer this kind of naming for side-effect-free methods thus eliminating the questions about empty-parens (IntelliJ guys can probably add an inspection for that)

Comment: @incarnate Interesting. The reason I bumped into your question was precisely because of the associated IntelliJ idea inspection: it keeps flagging toString, sometimes with and sometimes without parentheses (seems to depend on whatever the next parent uses), and I was looking to see what the convention should be. It would be good to have consistency at least in the Scala library, e.g. for FunctionN (has parens) and Iterator (doesn't). Consistency in the library would remove a lot of hassle with the inspections, which are otherwise generally very good to have.